# Create an API blueprint from entity specification

Tags: api, rest, crud, apiblueprint

I'm building an API and I have modeled the entities I need inside it. By example

**User**

- Name
- Email
- City

**Company**

- Name
- Website

I'm using Blueprint to specify the API itself and I need to create endpoints for CRUD operations in pretty much every entity. The task seems very redundant to me - besides some tuning that is needed in some specific entities, most of the basic skeleton looks like the same.

I wonder if there is any tool that allows me to write down my entities, its fields and types and generates this basic skeleton.

I was about to start creating one and then I stopped to look around if there already is one but I did not find anything yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API Blueprint contains a tool to write, use, reuse, compose, inherit your data structures, and it's [MSON](https://github.com/apiaryio/mson).

Basically it's a way to describe your data structures within an API Blueprint. We do also provide an html renderer for that, and it's the [Attributes Kit](https://github.com/apiaryio/attributes-kit). Try also to have a look to its [Playground](https://attributes-kit.herokuapp.com/).

You can find an useful tutorial on [official website](https://apiblueprint.org/documentation/mson/tutorial.html), as well more information.

Hopefully it should be enough to get started.

Cheers,
V.

Comment: Hi, Vincenzo! Thanks for the answer. I'm going to try this now and see if it works the way I intended

Comment: Well it is still not quite what I wanted but it sure did streamline things! Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify what's missing here?

Comment: Yes, sure - it is very common for entities to have CRUD endpoints. What happens is that we have to specify the data structure and all the four endpoints for each CRUD operation everytime. It would be really nice to specify the structure and automatically generate a boilerplate doc for GET and POST in the general endpoint `entity/` and GET, PUT, DELETE operations for `entity/{id}`

Comment: sorry for the late reply, by the way